# Can anyone tell me if I'm using the proper code to print the occurrences in this ArrayList?

Tags: java, find-occurrences

Okay, so what I'm trying to do is go through the ArrayList called theDateArray, do a search for a particular item in that list, and output how many times that item appears.  When I test it in the main class, it just outputs the number 0 no matter what date as a String I enter in.   Here is **part** of the class which the methods are in.  I don't think as of now it's necessary to include the entire class unless it is confusing...

```
  public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){

           int i;

           for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
               if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
                 theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
               }
             }
             for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
               System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
             }
             return theDateArray;
           }       



     public int getTickets(String date){
         int tix= theDateArray.indexOf(date);
         int occurrences= Collections.frequency(theDateArray, tix);
         if (tix>=0){
             System.out.println(occurrences);


         }
         return occurrences;
     }
```

Here is the made up tickets that I'm testing in my test class....

```
 public class AmusementParkTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    AmusementPark park1= new AmusementPark("Walden University Park");

    park1.addTicket(777, "Child", "Noah Johnson","2017-06-09" , 27.99, false);
    park1.addTicket(777, "Child", "Zachary Gibson","2017-06-09" , 27.99, false);
    System.out.println("The dates in which tickets are available are as follows: ");
    park1.getTicketDates();

            park1.getTickets("2017-06-09");

    }



}
```

Here is the output I'm getting....

```
    The dates in which tickets are available are as follows: 
    2017-06-09 
    2017-06-09 
    0
```

I want the 0 to be a 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these lines are your error:

```
int tix= theDateArray.indexOf(date);
int occurrences= Collections.frequency(theDateArray, tix);
```

You're looking for the frequency of the index of your date, so in your example the first index of `2017-06-09` date might be index 0?  So when you do Collections.frequency ... you're looking for the frequency of `0` within your date array, to which it returns 0 (no occurences).

I would try switching it over to

```
// find the number of occurrences of your passed in date within the date array
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(theDateArray, date)
```